# Malfunction of data copy from excel to Sql using BulkCopy (vb.net)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel

I'm searching the reason why is the importation from excel to Sql Table not working well (via vb.net)

The excel file in input contains 1300 rows and 12 columns. The five last columns contains prices.
After importation, my Table if well filled with the excel data except the two last "price" columns where all the data are 'Null'.
The strange thing is that all my "price" columns in the sql destination table are formatted with the same type (decimal(18,2)), even in the excel file.
For the copy, I use SqlBulkCopy and I wonder if this function is not limited.

Here's my code:

```
        Dim ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fTransp & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes""")

        ExcelConnection.Open()

        Dim RequeteExcelTransp As String = "SELECT * FROM [ExcelCetup$]"

        Dim objCmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(RequeteExcelTransp, ExcelConnection)

        Dim objDR As OleDbDataReader

        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(ConnexionLinkyStat)
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo." & TableTransp & ""

            Try
                objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
                objDR.Close()
                ConnexionLinkyStat.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Using

        ExcelConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Did you confirm those columns are getting read into `objDR` before trying the bulk copy?

Comment: @topshot Yes I confirm that objDR reads all the columns

Comment: I assume the column names are exactly the same but maybe try `SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping` just to make sure.